# Python C API, How to call base type method from subtype?

Tags: overriding, python-c-api, subtype

I created a subtype from one existing Python type with C API by following this guide [Python C API Defining New Types](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html)

I overridden one base type's method by registering the new method thanks to tp_methods attribute of the new PyTypeObject.
This is working fine.

But, the code must also be able to execute the base type method (the one that has been overrided. I can not find documentation on how to do it.

Any idea are welcome, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's 2.5 options, in order of complexity:

1. Just find the C function that defines it. When using the C API the chances are you're inheriting from a known class that is implemented in C. In that case you'd track down the C function used for the method and call that.
2. Get the class from the object, the base from the class:

   a. `PyObject* baseclass = self->ob_type->tp_base;`

   b. Use the C API equivalent of `super()`:

   `PyObject* baseclass = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(&PySuper_Type,self->ob_type,self,NULL);`

   With the base found you can then use the C API equivalent of getattr to get the relevant function:

.

```
/* check baseclass against null */
PyObject* func = PyObject_GetAttrString(baseclass,"function_name");
/* check func is not null */
PyObject* result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(self,other_arguments..., NULL); /* adjust arguments here */
Py_DECREF(func);
// decref result?
```

You can use a different method of calling it but you need to make sure you pass self with the arguments.

---

Option 2b is probably most flexible since it should work when multiple bases are defined through the `tp_bases`.

Comment: Thanks DavidW,   

your answer did 99% of the job.
I post in the next answer my code, since I had to do some little corrections to your proposed code.

Answer (score 1):

I post here my working code largely inspired from DavidW answer. Modifications are:
1/Cast subtype object instance (self) to PyObject pointer for ob_type access.
2/ Use func as PyObject_CallFunctionObjArg first parameter instead of self.

```
PyObject* baseclass = ((PyObject*)self)->ob_type->tp_base;
if (baseclass == NULL) {...}
PyObject* func = PyObject_GetAttrString(baseclass,"sum");
if (func == NULL) { ... }
PyObject* result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(func,self, NULL);
Py_DECREF(func);
```